# How to modify a keyboard shortcut Nemo v2.8.7?

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, configuration, shortcuts, nemo

I've browsed around this forum to find an answer for it but the answers that I found never worked. Some answers suggest that there is a folder `~/.gnome2/accels/nemo` which there isn't on my machine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try creating a file `~/.config/nemo/accels` because that's similar to Nautilus's keyboard shortcuts file, `~/.config/nautilus/accels`